# My cs class can't be open and showing encoding error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I just working on my graduation project and after 2 days the deadline . just when I was checking the last review I clicked on my class "book.cs" and it can't be load . tried to open it using other ways . it's show all the lines like a blocks"[]" . I did not made any changes and don't know what to do ..

you can check this image that I can't open the file and the error # ..

[image]

in 1- it's not showing the arrow 
2- errors I got

please help and many thanks ..

Comment: Try opening the file in Notepad to see if the file itself is corrupt. If so, restore it from a backup.

Comment: Tried , it's open an empty file but when I press ctrl+a it's selecting all the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file has become corrupt. You have two options, one of which is greatly preferable to the other, in my opinion. The first (preferable) option is to recover the file from backup. The second option is to open the file using a text editor and remove the characters that is causing it to be corrupt.

Comment: I thinks you are right , and that was a good thing to make me always make a backups ... i'll write it again :(